# How to get only list of products that are selected inside the bundle product in magento2

Tags: magento2

How to get only list of products that are selected inside the bundle product in magento2
when we create a bundle product we can selects some products to attach in bundle products i just want to show these attached products on detail page

Comment: Programatically right ?

Comment: yes Programatically

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet code to get all the selection products of bundle product:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;


class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper 
{
    /**
     * @var Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    public function getBundleProductOptionsData()
    {

        $productId = 40; //any bundle product id
        $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($productId);
        //get all the selection products used in bundle product.
        $selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getSelectionsCollection(
                $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product),
                $product
            );

        foreach ($selectionCollection as $proselection) {
            $selectionArray = [];
            $selectionArray['selection_product_name'] = $proselection->getName();
            $selectionArray['selection_product_quantity'] = $proselection->getPrice();
            $selectionArray['selection_product_price'] = $proselection->getSelectionQty();
            $selectionArray['selection_product_id'] = $proselection->getProductId();
            $productsArray[$proselection->getOptionId()][$proselection->getSelectionId()] = $selectionArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if this code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach ($collection as $item) {


    $data[] = $item->getId().", ".$item->getTypeId().", - , ".$item->getSku().", ".$item->getPackSize().", ".$visibility.", ".$status.", ".$item->getPrice().",  ".str_replace(',', '/',$item->getName()).", ";
    $children = [];
    if ($type == 'configurable') {
        $children = $item->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($item);

    } elseif ($type == 'bundle') {
        $children = $item->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getSelectionsCollection($item->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($item), $item)->getItems();
    } elseif ($type == 'grouped') {
        $children = $item->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($item);
    }

    if($children) {
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $data[] = $child->getId().", ".$child->getTypeId().", ".$item->getSku().", ".$child->getSku().", ".str_replace(',', '/',$child->getAttributeText('status')).", ".$child->getPrice().", ".str_replace(',' ".str_replace(',', '/',$child->getName()).", ";
        }
    }
}
```